# CakePHP 3: belongsToMany (through) and additional associations

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have defined the following associations:

```
class RecipesTable extends Table
{
  $this->belongsToMany('Ingredients', [
    'through' => 'RecipesIngredients',
    'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'ingredient_id',
  ]);

class IngredientsTable extends Table
{
  $this->belongsToMany('Recipes', [
    'through' => 'RecipesIngredients',
    'foreignKey' => 'ingredient_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'recipe_id',
  ]);

class RecipesIngredientsTable extends Table
{
  $this->belongsTo('Recipes');
  $this->belongsTo('Ingredients');
  $this->belongsTo('Units');
```

The table 'RecipesIngredients' has the following structure:

```
id | recipe_id | ingredient_id | unit_id | ...
```

Now I make a request like the one below to get Recipes and the associated Ingredients. But without the Units.

```
$data = $this->Recipe->find('all')
    ->where('Recipe.id' => 55)
    ->contain(['Ingredient', ...])
    ->all();
```

My question is: how do I get the data of the associated 'Units' in a call of `$this->Recipe`?

I tried different contains like `->contain(['Ingredient' => ['Unit'], ...])` (and so on) but this doesn't work. CakePHP just returns the associated `ingredients` and the contents of the 'through' join table without linking to the associated `units`. Or gives an error of missing associations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work using `contain()`, at least not with a `belongsToMany` association, as the on-the-fly created intermediate association for the join table is being created too late for the eager loader to recognize it.

What you can do is explicitly create the otherwise on-the-fly generated `hasMany` association for the join table manually, eg on the `RecipesTable` class add:

```
$this->hasMany('RecipesIngredients', [
    'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id'
]);
```

Then you can contain your associations like:

```
->contain(['RecipesIngredients' => ['Ingredients', 'Units']])
```

Comment: Ok yes. I already thought about this. It would have been great to fetch the data without accessing the 'through' table in between.