# CakePHP: Retreiving a column from the join table in a belongsToManay relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, has-and-belongs-to-many, join

My application allows a user to create `scenarios` by linking together `soe_blocks`. In turn, `soe_blocks` refer to a variable number of `soe_entries`.

To build `scenarios`, `soe_blocks` are linked to the `scenario` and ordered by an `offset`. The `soe_blocks` can be used in many different `scenarios`. `soe_entries` can relate only to a single `soe_block`

[image: MySQL Workbench model]

I *think* the relationship is defined as:

- `scenarios` belongsToMany `soe_blocks` through `scenarios_soe_blocks`
- `soe_blocks` belongsToMany `scenarios` through `scenarios_soe_blocks`
- `scenarios_soe_blocks` is where the `offset` is kept
- `soe_entries` haveOne `soe_blocks`

Tables:

```
scenarios: id | name
     data: 0, 'scenario_1'

soe_blocks: id | name
      data: 0, 'soe_block_1'
            1, 'soe_block_2'

scenarios_soe_blocks: id | scenario_id | soe_block_id | offset
                data: 1, 0, 1, 1
                      2, 0, 2, 2
```

Models:

```
class ScenariosTable extends Table
{
    $this->belongsToMany('SoeBlocks', [
        'foreignKey' => 'scenario_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'soe_block_id',
        'through' => 'ScenariosSoeBlocks',
        'joinTable' => 'soe_blocks'
    ]);
}

class SoeBlocksTable extends Table
{
    $this->belongsToMany('Scenarios', [
        'foreignKey' => 'soe_block_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'scenario_id',
        'joinTable' => 'scenarios_soe_blocks',
        'through' => 'ScenariosSoeBlocks'
    ]);
}

class ScenariosSoeBlocksTable extends Table
    $this->belongsTo('SoeBlocks', [
        'foreignKey' => 'soe_block_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

Controllers:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $scenario = $this->Scenarios->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['SoeBlocks', 'RunStatus', 'ScenarioLog']
    ]);

    $this->set('scenario', $scenario);
}
```

As far as I can make out from [CakePHP Doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option), this is all I need. But I couldn't get the `ScenarioController->view()` method to return the `offsets` from the `scenarios_soe_blocks` table associated with the `soe_blocks`.

I tried to add `ScenariosSoeBlocks` into the `'contain'` clause in the ScenarioController, but got the error: `Scenarios is not associated with ScenariosSoeBlocks`. I found an [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178005/cakephp-3-belongstomany-through-and-additional-associations) article that suggested I add the following to the ScenarioTable:

```
  $this->hasMany('ScenariosSoeBlocks', [
        'foreignKey' => 'scenario_id'
    ]);
```

This seems to have worked, and now I can request `ScenariosSoeBlocks` in my controller like this:

```
$scenario = $this->Scenarios->get($id, [
   'contain' => ['SoeBlocks', 'ScenariosSoeBlocks', 'RunStatus', 'ScenarioLog']
]);
```

Which at least gets the data into the view template, but not in the single object I'm hoping for. Eventually, I want to be able to CRUD the `soe_blocks` along with their associated `soe_entries`, in an object that looks like this:

```
offset | soe_block_id | soe_entry_id |
```

I have many other questions, like how to save etc., but I figured I need to get this working first.

So, my questions for now are:

- are my associations correct?
- how do I retrieve all the associations to view?

Answer (score 1):

> are my associations correct?

The first two are, but then it should be:

- `soe_blocks` hasOne `soe_entries`
- `soe_entries` belongsTo `soe_blocks`

> how do I retrieve all the associations to view?

By containing them, just like you did in your first example. This question seems to originate from the question how to access the join table data, which is very simple, the join table data is being set on the target table entity (`Scenario` or `SoeBlock`, depending on from which side/table you issue the query), in a property named `_joinData`:

```
$joinTableEntity = $scenario->soe_blocks[0]->_joinData;
$offset = $joinTableEntity->offset;
```

You can easily gather information about the data structure by dumping your entity contents:

```
debug($scenario);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving Additional Data to the Join Table](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-additional-data-to-the-join-table)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found that the mistake I had made was creating a controller for the join table, when in fact, that should be left somewhat opaque. You are correct about those two missing relationship descriptions - I had left them off because I was more focused on the join table part of the problem.